# github new repo .gitignore CSharp missing

Tags: github, gitignore

I am trying to create a new repo for my project (C#), but I can't find the CSharp language in the list of languages in .gitignore list as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As commented in [issue 1514](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1514)

> We did this a while ago for VisualStudio - which was a combination of CSharp and VisualBasic languages -

(It was in [Dec. 2012: PR 492](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/492))

So use the VisualStudio one.

Comment: Choosing "VisualStudio" after seeing the others based on languages was not intuitively obvious.  I was looking around for C# or CSharp. Thanks for posting this answer.